# Affect the same value to a select and input onclick

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a select and an input for each line.

Actually, the "Repeat for the whole stay" will put the value of the first input on the others one.

Now, I want to be able by clicking on the same "Repeat for the whole stay" link to repeat the value of the select on the left.

Actually it working well for the input but not for the select:

```
$('#repeatRate').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rate = $(this).prev('input').val();
    $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val(rate);
});
```

How I can make it possible for the select too when I click on the "Repeat for the whole stay" button ?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kwj3p6tt/

Comment: Can you please clarify, it's really hard to read and understand what you want right now?

Comment: Actually the "Repeat for the whole stay" link will copy the first input to the other one. I want the same link makes the same but for the select on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").val($('select option:selected').first().val());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwj3p6tt/5/

Comment: what doesn't work?  You said  "Repeat for the whole stay" link to repeat the value of the select on the left. the first select value is repeated for all select values. what is your requirement?

Comment: If I select on the first select the third value, the second will be copied. It should be the third one too.

Comment: sorry I have absolutely no idea what you are asking for

Comment: See here please: https://jsfiddle.net/kwj3p6tt/7/. Select on the first select "Spécial pompiers" and click on the link.

Comment: you have all of your values set to 3.  wouldn't you want distinct values?  https://jsfiddle.net/kwj3p6tt/8/